# Iphone App Crash on Running

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

I made a simple application on XCode 4.2 and Sqllite.
It runs on Simulator smoothly. I made its build and run on Iphone 4S with iOS 5. 
it Runs and crash without any error.
Guide me to detect the problem.

Comment: How did you get a version of 5.2?

Comment: paste crash log and the code where is crashing

Comment: @AlexTerente No I cannot Run it Directly because my mac version is 10.6.8 and XCode 4.2 while I have Iphone 4S with IOS 5.1. so due to some comparability issue i cannot run code direct to device. I have to make a build then run it.

Comment: At least read the crash log from organizer. You should update

Comment: @AlexTerente its not Crashing on Simulator, its crashing on device. How to get the log from device?

Comment: See your crash log in xcode-organizer (Organizer/Devices/Device Logs) of Xcode.. when you run in device just need to connect your device to xcode..

Comment: @Jagdish I am new in Iphone Development I cannot understand the log. I may paste it over here you can tell me the problem?

Comment: @AmirIphone Connect your device to Mac, Open Xcode, Open Organizer inside xcode. Than see Devices Section, you may get your device name.. Than see Device Logs. Now you run your app in device only not from xcode to device..  you will get same Console output see in Organizer Device Log..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect your device to Mac, Open Xcode, Open Organizer inside xcode. Than see Devices Section, you may get your device name.. Than see Device Logs. Now you run your app in device only not from xcode to device.. you will get same Console output see in Organizer Device Log

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging on the device in your app delegate or if need be in your main.m file.

Also check the Console app on your Mac.

It contains device logs you might use to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

make sure about ur version. and did you have the provisioning profile and certificate installed to push the kit in the device?
if you dont have any provisioning profile associated with the iphone it wont let you push or run the kit on your device..

Answer (score 0):

Has the app ever worked on the iPhone?

If so, you may have changed the datamodel, which would cause the app to stop working.

You'll have to delete the app from the phone, then re run it.